# spring entity to DTO with compute getter

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, dto, mapstruct

Trying to understand the best practice here, i have an entity
and i add some login to the getPrice property:

```
public class Order{
 
    private Integer price;
    private Integer addOn;

    public Integer setAddOn(Integer addOn){
       this.addOn=addOn;
    }
    public Integer getAddOn(){
       return addOn;
    }
    public Integer setPrice(Integer price){
       this.price=price;
    }
    // standard getters and setters
    public Integer getPrice(){
      if(addOn==null){
       return price;
      }
      else{
        return addOn+price;
      }
    }
}
```

and a DTO

```
public class OrderDTO{
 
    private Integer price;
    private Integer addOn;

    // getters and setters
}
```

the issue is that when I am mapping the order to orderDTO the price in the DTO is changing
since the entity price getter is calculating.

```
    OrderDTO orderDTO= modelMapper.map(order, OrderDTO.class);
```

what's the best approach here?
thanks

Comment: Hi, could you please add some simple reproducible example, not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: thanks i added some more code - hope its clear

Comment: You do not want to map calculated getPrice method to the price field in DTO. You need just perform mapping of price field( without addon adjustment) to DTO price field. Correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Currently, MapStruct only supports mapping from public fields/properties. See contributor [comment and issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1689#issuecomment-455698321).

**Solution 1: using MapStruct, create a separate getter for the problematic field**

Objects:

```java
public class Order {

    private Integer price;
    private Integer addOn;
    

    public void setAddOn(Integer addOn){
        this.addOn=addOn;
    }

    public Integer getAddOn(){
        return addOn;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price){
        this.price=price;
    }

    public Integer getFullPrice() {
        if (addOn == null) {
            return getPrice();
        } else {
            return addOn + getPrice();
        }
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}

public class OrderDTO {

    private Integer price;
    private Integer addOn;

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getAddOn() {
        return addOn;
    }

    public void setAddOn(Integer addOn) {
        this.addOn = addOn;
    }
}
```

Mapper:

```java
@Mapper
public interface OrderMapper {
    OrderMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(OrderMapper.class);

    OrderDTO map(Order order);
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class OrderMapperImpl implements OrderMapper {

    @Override
    public OrderDTO map(Order order) {
        if ( order == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO();

        orderDTO.setPrice( order.getPrice() );
        orderDTO.setAddOn( order.getAddOn() );

        return orderDTO;
    }
}
```

Example of using:

```java
    @Test
    public void mapperMapStructTest() {

        Integer price = 100;
        Integer addOn = 10;
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setAddOn(addOn);
        order.setPrice(price);
        OrderDTO orderDTO = OrderMapper.INSTANCE.map(order);

        Assert.assertEquals(orderDTO.getPrice(), price);
        Assert.assertEquals(orderDTO.getAddOn(), addOn);
    }
```

**Solution 2: using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs), do not change structure of object**

Unlike MapStruct, Jackson can access private fields thru reflection. The main advantage of that solution is that you do not need to add an additional getter for accessing the problematic field.

```java
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void mapperTest() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //configuring Jackson ObjectMapper to access private fields
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

        Integer price = 100;
        Integer addOn = 10;
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setAddOn(addOn);
        order.setPrice(price);
        OrderDTO orderDTO = objectMapper.convertValue(order, OrderDTO.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(orderDTO.getPrice(), price);
        Assert.assertEquals(orderDTO.getAddOn(), addOn);
    }
}
```

**Summary:**
I think the first solution is preferable. It is simple and has better performance than the second solution because for conversion Jackson will use reflection to access private fields and use intermediate JSON object.